# can't press two buttons simultaneously on infrared sauna curcuitboard

Tags: button

I have an infrared sauna at home that I'd like to hook up to a wifi-controlled outlet and control via the internet.  It's a pretty basic made-in-China kind of a cabin, so I'm going to have to implement all the bells and whistles myself.

I've taken off the piezo speaker (so it doesn't beep at me for pressing buttons) and I am able to bridge the connection so the "add more time" button is always being pressed down.

The problem is that the circuit board apparently can't listen to more than one button being pressed simultaneously.  If I'm pressing "add more time" I can't press "power on".  Every time I reconnect the sauna to power I have to re-press the power button.

Are there any heuristics to take the power button on the circuit board out of the equation, to make the sauna always be "on" if it's getting electricity?  I really think that's the shortest path to success here.

I *recognize* this question doesn't have all the details you need.  I don't know what those are.

Comment: I think you just can't press several buttons at once, you need to find a way to automatically "press" the buttons sequentially instead.

Comment: Content-wise, agreeing with @OskarSkog here. Just a friendly pointer: please don't write things like "my question is bad. If you find it bad, please don't react to it". Avoiding downvotes that way a) won't work and b) should not work, since the idea of this website **is** that bad questions get downvoted until you improve them. The proper procedure is to react to issues raised in the comments :) That way, you can continously improve your question. I removed that anti-"democratically-downvote" statement from your question. It's really better without :)

Comment: So: let's get started with this! Can you describe on what you measured across these switches when the device is powered off? is it possible that some of the buttons' pins are directly connected, even if no button is pressed?

Comment: hey @MarcusMüller but think of it this way.  if you guys point me to success this weekend, i can have a sauna.  then i can delete my question (please request) and your board will be nice and pretty again.  if you guys punitively delete my question i can have no sauna.

Comment: @MarcusMüller responding to your questions (thanks).. i haven't.  i'm so much more basic than that.  i can certainly look up how to do that and post back.  i *thought* about putting in a passive low-pass RC filter (i think it's just a capacitator and a resistor chained together?) on the line out from the "turn up" button, as that would solve "who gets there first", but then i wouldn't be able to press "turn up" as the circuitboard is busy listening to "turn on".    any heuristics here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @WalrustheCat that approach (and your considerations regarding it) would be something that would make a great addition to your question!

Answer (score 0):

This feels very much like your sauna controller, either by physical or software limitations, simply *can't* deal with multiple button presses at once.

You had a rather nice approach here:

> i thought about putting in a passive low-pass RC filter (i think it's just a capacitator and a resistor chained together?) on the line out from the "turn up" button, as that would solve "who gets there first", but then i wouldn't be able to press "turn up" as the circuitboard is busy listening to "turn on".

So, your idea is to add a low pass that basically delays your first turn up button press. Adding a delay: **excellent idea!**

So, for me, this looks a lot like you know damn better than the Sauna manufacturer what you want of your control panel :)

That, in turn means that you'd be the right one to design something that "pushes the right buttons in the right order" for you.

In the case of the turn-up button: It feels like a simple timer IC like the often-referred-to-yet-horrible 555 would actually do, if you drove e.g. a transistor with it that "shorts" the button.

The real question here becomes is what "makes the button act like a button", because that defines how you can simulate a button press.

Is it an opener, closer? Does it connect supply voltage to a pin that is otherwise tied to ground? Or the other way around? Or is it actually a clever button matrix where the microcontroller of the Sauna sequentially checks which pins are connected?

In the worst case, I'd still expect a small relay, driven by your logic (maybe through a transistor) in place of the original button to work. It's probably still easier to figure out how both contacts of the switches relate (i.e. which one has the higher voltage?) and just use transistors to replace the switches.

Now, to control these switch-replacements:

I mentioned the 555, as it can do something like an adjustable delay, or a periodic defined-length pulse. That way, you could emulate someone waiting e.g 10s after power has come on, and then pressing the "up" button ceaselessly every 0.5s for 0.1s or so.

I personally don't like the 555 very much, as more complicated circuits than what is described above often end up being very complicated and inaccurate. From my perspective, a simple microcontroller would do the job very well. If you have an Arduino, an Arduino-compatible board, or an [mbed platform board](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/?tvend=10) (the simpler ones of these often can be had for but a handful or two of dollars), you might have a pretty easy time writing firmware that does exactly what you want now – and in the future. For example, one could imagine you add a digital temperature sensors (with I²C connectivity) in your sauna. Your controller could then query that sensor regularly, run a clever control loop and switch the heating on or off so that you always run at target temperature. Or you add a humidity sensor and a small pump that sprays water :D The sky is pretty much the limit as soon as your logic gets flexible!